# Align formula with amsmath

Tags: vertical-alignment, amsmath

I know similar questions have already been asked, but still I couldn't get the alignment to work. I know that `align` is supposed to replace `eqnarray`, but I just don't manage to achieve the same alignment. So I've got a calculation that I'd like to center around the equality sign. Here is a stupid MWE:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
& \frac{1}{2} & = 0.5 \\
&& = 0.25 + 0.25 \\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the second part of the formula is aligned on the right side. Is there a way to put the equality signs one under the other instead?

Comment: Use only one `&` on each line. Also, remove the break line  from the second line. `\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2} &= 0.5 \\ &= 0.25 + 0.25 \end{align*}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the leading `&` on both lines.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2} & = 0.5 \\
& = 0.25 + 0.25
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

> [image]